# Have to manually restart NetworkManager to get WiFi to work

Tags: 18.04, wireless, network-manager

After every single reboot, I have to manually restart the NetworkManager, so that the Wifi does connect, which makes it impossible to run truly headless.

OS: Ubuntu 18.04
Hardware: Jetson Nano

this is the command I have to run:

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

How can I make it autoconnect? And how to troubleshoot this issue further?

Best regards

Comment: v18.04 is shortly to go EOL. The current LTS 22.04 already features this. Time to upgrade methinks.

Comment: Nvidia isn't releasing any major updates for the Jetson Nano anymore, so it's unfortunately gonna stay on 18.04.

Comment: What results for `cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`

Comment: Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/05/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-begins-31-may-2023/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 18.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com//blog/18-04-end-of-standard-support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was an easy fix. I had to register the service for it to autostart!

```
sudo systemctl enable NetworkManager
```

Now the Wifi works fine after rebooting.